# FancyBox Callback Keydown

Tags: jquery, keyboard, callback, fancybox

I have been working on this code, and I can't seem to figure it out. 
Fancybox's callbacks don't seem to work at all. I have the keyboard bound to the pagination for this gallery. But I want to unbind the keyboard from the table when fancybox opens. When fancybox opens nothing changes....
What to do??

$(document).ready(function() {

```
$('a.active').click(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#ajaxTable').load(url+'/1');

    return false;
});

$("a.fancy").fancybox({
            callbackOnStart: function() {   $('a#gleft a#gright').unbind("keydown"); },         
            'frameWidth': 570, 
            'frameHeight':  470


})



$(document).keydown(function(event) {
            if(event.keyCode == 37 ) {

                var url = $('a#gleft').attr('href');
                if (url != null) {
                    $('#ajaxTable').load(url+'/1');
                    $(document).unbind("keydown");
                }
            } else if(event.keyCode == 39 ) {
                var url = $('a#gright').attr('href');
                if (url != null) {
                    $('#ajaxTable').load(url+'/1');
                    $(document).unbind("keydown");
                }
            }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

If you're targeting two elements separately it would be

```
$('a#gleft, a#gright')
```